# How can I make an "on hold button" in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I'm developing a game for android in libgdx, I first ran it as a desktop app and it ran great.
In the game if you press the fly button a force is applied on the character like so:

```
player.getBody().applyForceToCenter(0,70f,true);
```

So as long as the button is pressed the character will fly up.

This was my code using the keyboard input:

```
 if(MyInput.isPressed(MyInput.BUTTON1)){
        player.stopMove();
            //if(myContactListener.isPlayerOnGround()){
        player.moveUp();
        isPressed = true;
            //  }
    }

public class MyInput {

public static boolean[] keys;
public static boolean[] pkeys;
public static final int NUM_KEYS = 1;
public static final int BUTTON1 = 0;



static{
    keys = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];
    pkeys = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];
}
public static void update(){
    for(int i = 0;i<NUM_KEYS;i++){
        pkeys[i] = keys[i];
    }
}
public static void setKey(int i,boolean b){keys[i] = b;}
public static boolean isPressed(int i){return keys[i] && pkeys[i];}
```

}

```
public class MyInputPocessor implements InputProcessor {
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int k){
    if(k == Input.Keys.UP){
        MyInput.setKey(MyInput.BUTTON1,true);
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean keyUp(int k){
    if(k == Input.Keys.UP){
        MyInput.setKey(MyInput.BUTTON1,false);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code ran great while I was using the keyboard, but now I'm trying to run the game on my android phone, so I created a button for that:

```
button.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                                 int pointer, int button) {
            player.getBody().applyForceToCenter(0,70f,true);
            return true;
        }
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                            int pointer, int button) {
            player.setState(STANDING);
        }
    });
```

But with this listener I can only make the player jump once every click, and not keep jumping while the button is pressed.

In short,

How can I implement a button listener which will keep the player jumping as long as the button is pressed in libgdx (BOX2D)

Please help.

Comment: Just set some boolean to true inside touchDown() and to false inside touchUp(), then somewhere inside render/update apply force to your body depend on that flag state. That should do the trick.

Comment: I agree with @Metaphore. What he is saying is correct. Your call only comes once on touch down and once on touch up.You may need to set a schedular or a bool which controls the same.

Comment: Yeah you are right, that did the trick

Comment: Why not use GestureDetector? https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html